# Парсинг xml-файла с помощью XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlparser

Не могу достать текст из xml-файла:

```
<reference>
<![CDATA[ demo_1 ]]>
</reference>
<price>
<![CDATA[ 16.510000 ]]>
</price>
<name>
<language id="1" xlink:href="http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/languages/1">
<![CDATA[ Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts ]]>
</language>
<language id="2" xlink:href="http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/languages/2">
<![CDATA[ T-shirt délavé à manches courtes ]]>
</language>
</name>
```

Нужно достать то что внутри `<![CDATA[ demo_1 ]]>`
Например -  "demo_1",  "16.510000",  "Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts".

Использую XmlPullParser.

```
private void parseXmlResponse(String RESPONSE_STRNG_HERE) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (factory != null) {
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        }
        XmlPullParser xpp = null;
        if (factory != null) {
            xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        }
        if (xpp != null) {
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(RESPONSE_STRNG_HERE));
        }
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag " + xpp.getName());
                Log.e("Count ----------", "" + xpp.getAttributeCount());

                int ia;
                for (ia = 0; ia < xpp.getAttributeCount(); ia++) {

                    switch (xpp.getName()) {
                        case "id_default_image":
                            if(ia%2==0) {
                                id_default_image.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                                Log.d(TAG, "getAttributeValue" + xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                            }
                             break;

                          case "name":
                              Log.d(TAG, "getAttributeValue" + xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                              break;
                          case "language":
                              Log.d(TAG, "getAttributeValue" + xpp.nextText());
                              break;
                          case "description":
                              xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("language");

                              Log.d(TAG, "getAttributeValue" + xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                              break;
                          case "reference":
                              Log.d(TAG, "getAttributeValue" + xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                              break;
                          case "price":
                              Log.d(TAG, "getAttributeValue" + xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                              break;
                    }
                      Log.e("Attribute Name ", xpp.getAttributeName(ia));
                      Log.e("Attribute Value ", xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
                }

            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag ------------- " + xpp.getName());
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT ) {

                if(xpp.getText().length() > 3 ){

                    Log.e(TAG,"Text===="+ xpp.getText());
                    text.add(xpp.getText());
                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А не лучше парсить чем-то нормальным? XmlPullParser все-таки больше для потрохов ОС Android.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать ответ